# ARRAYFORMULA with GOOGLEFINANCE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I want to create a simple function that returns company name for every line that is filled with the **Symbol** via **GoogleFinance** function, however, I am not able to make the script work for every line.

**Here is the example:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJDq0smLUmbylAnAep3WIz41GvqH_dhpnLjnLEpOmAQ/edit?usp=sharing

**CODE 1:**

```
// DOES NOT WORK    
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(ROW(B:B)=1,"NAME",A:A="","",TRUE,VLOOKUP(GOOGLEFINANCE(A:A, "name"),GOOGLEFINANCE(A:A, "name"),1,0)))
```

Once I change the **A:A** to **A2** it loads the data correctly, but I did not find a way of repeating the function for each row

**I tried a workaround:**

```
// DOES NOT WORK
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(ROW(B:B)=1;"NAME";A:A="";"";TRUE;VLOOKUP(GOOGLEFINANCE(CONCATENATE("A";row()); "name");GOOGLEFINANCE(CONCATENATE("A";row()); "name");1;0)))
```

But the same result..

Any ideas how to make it work?

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Please note that Excel does not have `GOOGLEFINANCE` nor `ARRAYFORMULA`. As such, any Excel tag is irrelevant, and I have removed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use this**

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IF(r="",,GOOGLEFINANCE(r, "name"))))
```

[image]

**Or this with the header**

```
={"Name";BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IF(r="",,GOOGLEFINANCE(r, "name"))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Working! Thank you very much Osm! ❤️

Comment: Hi Osm, I would love to use this piece of code but I need to do an IF statement to do the calculation only if in column C is stock type "Dividend" here is the piece of the code

```={"DIVIDEND"; BYROW(A2:A; LAMBDA(r;IF(C:C="Dividend";IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=";r);'XML IMPORT'!C$3);".";",")/4);"-")))}```

I was thinking about ```r(C:C)``` but it did not work - any idea, please? :-)

Comment: Hi @vohratom glad to hear back from you, make sure to see [Should posts be self-contained?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); you have to [Ask a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with Google-sheet tag, the answers meant to benefit the poster and future visitors as well. see you [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets).

Comment: Great point, thank you @Osm! Just posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020088/how-to-execute-the-function-only-when-there-is-a-specific-value-in-another-colum

Comment: Nice solution... I was just facing this too. FOr some reason `Filter` doesn't work, but byRow does...? weird, but manageable!