# How to execute the function only when there is a specific value in another column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, import, google-sheets-formula

**Dear StackOverFlow users**,

I would love to create a function that will do the calculation based on the specific value in another column.

[image]

| SYMBOL | NAME | STOCK TYPE | DIVIDEND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAL | American Airlines Group Inc | Growth | Do this "(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=";r);'XML IMPORT'!C$3);".";",")/4)" only if C:C="Dividend" else "-" |
| T | AT&T Inc. | Dividend | Do this "(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=";r);'XML IMPORT'!C$3);".";",")/4)" only if C:C="Dividend" else "-" |

**Example xls is here:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y6d0_0x_8aooy9iYfc9HtspwBpN6k5mJV5TKeOsnjcQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IF`:

```
=IF(C3="Dividend"; SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&A3; 'XML IMPORT'!C$3); "."; ",")/4; "-")
```

array would be:

```
={"DIVIDEND";INDEX(MAP(C2:C; A2:A; LAMBDA(c; a; IF(c="Dividend"; SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&a; 'XML IMPORT'!C$3); "."; ",")/4; "-"))))}
```